# How to generate an RSA public key using a CSR file in C#?

Tags: c#, openssl, cryptography, rsa, x509

I have 2 lines of openssl commands that work and generate the public key that would work with an api that requires it to function:

```
openssl req -new -utf8 -nameopt multiline,utf8 -config fa.cnf -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout fa.key -out fa.csr
openssl req -in fa.csr -noout -pubkey -out publickey.pem
```

As far as I understand the command, it first try to generate a `.csr` file using `fa.cnf` config file and an RSA private key and save them in `fa.csr` and `fa.csr` files relatively. then, it generates the public key by specifying the `.csr` file.
Here is the configuration file:

```
[req]
prompt = no
distinguished_name = dn

[dn]
CN=MyCompany [Stamp]
serialNumber = 12345678910
O = Non-Governmental
C = US
```

I've tried to implement the exact procedure in C#, and this is as far as I could get:

```
var subjectName = "CN=MyCompany [Stamp],O=Non-Governmental,serialNumber=12345678910,C=US";

// Create new Object for Issuer and Subject
var subject = new X509Name(subjectName);

// Generate the key Value Pair, which in our case is a public Key
var randomGenerator = new CryptoApiRandomGenerator();
var random = new SecureRandom(randomGenerator);
const int strength = 2048;
var keyGenerationParameters = new KeyGenerationParameters(random, strength);

var keyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
keyPairGenerator.Init(keyGenerationParameters);
var subjectKeyPair = keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();

using (var fw = File.CreateText("fa.key"))
{
    var writer = new PemWriter(fw);
    writer.WriteObject(subjectKeyPair.Private);
}

//PKCS #10 Certificate Signing Request
var csr = new Pkcs10CertificationRequest("SHA1WITHRSA", subject, subjectKeyPair.Public, null, subjectKeyPair.Private);

//Convert BouncyCastle CSR to .PEM file.
var CSRPem = new StringBuilder();
var CSRPemWriter = new PemWriter(new StringWriter(CSRPem));
CSRPemWriter.WriteObject(csr);
CSRPemWriter.Writer.Flush();

//get CSR text
var CSRtext = CSRPem.ToString();

// Write content into a Txt file
using (StreamWriter f = new StreamWriter(@"fa.csr"))
{
    f.Write(CSRtext);
}

var publicKey = csr.GetPublicKey();

using (var fw = File.CreateText("publickey.pem"))
{
    var writer = new PemWriter(fw);
    writer.WriteObject(publicKey);
}
```

But the generated public key file is not valid. and the api doesn't work. I don't understand why it doesn't work or which part I've messed up. The only difference between the files generated by these 2 methods is the header of the private key file `fa.key` which writes this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Instead of this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I appreciate anyone who could lead me the right direction or introduce me a library that could make it easy to generate the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly well built in for .NET 7.  For older .NETs the PEM-exporting methods don't exist, but converting the binary data to PEM is fairly easy (with the PemEncoding class (.NET 5+), or just a helper function).

```
using (RSA key = RSA.Create(2048))
{
    CertificateRequest request = new CertificateRequest(
        "CN=MyCompany [Stamp], O=Non-Governmental, serialNumber=12345678910, C=US",
        key,
        HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
        RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

    // other stuff could have modified the request here, but you aren't
    // using any of the extra fancy options

    File.WriteAllText("fa.key", key.ExportPkcs8PrivateKeyPem());
    File.WriteAllText("fa.csr", request.CreateSigningRequestPem());
    File.WriteAllText("publickey.pem", key.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfoPem());
}
```

I've gone ahead and upgraded this to SHA-256, which is probably what the OpenSSL command is already doing.  (Also because CertificateRequest doesn't support SHA-1, as it was already a broken algorithm when CertificateRequest was built)

Comment: that is much cleaner and compact code, thank you. but it won't still work as the api reject the key generated. I think the code is still differ from the command since the length of the generated keys (private, public and csr) are not equal in both methods.

Comment: At the end turned out that the api, has some delay time verifying the public key and your code is completely valid. but now I should figure out how to implement this in .net standard.